# How to prepare a SQL query using Excel workbook data?

Tags: sql, excel

Can any answer how to prepare a SQL query from Excel sheet

Example

```
PNAME | INSTITUTE | COURSE | COURSE FEE
ANAND | SABHARI | PGDCA | 4500
ALTAF | COIT | DCA | 7200
```

I need a query like...

```
INSERT INTO STUDIES VALUES('ANAND','SABHARI','PGDCA',4500)
INSERT INTO STUDIES VALUES('ALTAF','COIT','DCA',7200)
```

Comment: Export the XLS file to a CSV file, and load it into MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

Wild guess as your not being specific but you want to generate the statements with a formula?

In E2:

```
="INSERT INTO STUDIES VALUES('" & A2 & "','" & B2 & "','" & C2 & "'," & D2 & ")"
```

and drag down. (best to pre-replace any `'` with `''` also)